# Why is my line not breaking when I use "\n" in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use this hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var arrText = txt.split('*');
  arrText.map((line, index) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTexto((prev) => {
        return (prev += line + '\n');
      });
    }, 300 * index),
  );
}, []);
```

And it simply rejects my `\n` and if I try to return JSX (the line in a paragraph), it becomes a `[object object]`

Can you please help me? <3

Comment: Where or how do you render the value set by `setTexto` (it's probably named `texto`)?

Comment: Use <br> instead if you're in a browser.

Comment: You can try using back ticks i.e. return (`${prev += line} + \n`), or as lukas said, use <br>

Comment: Define "rejects the `\n`". A newline in the *browser* is just whitespace and will be collapsed unless it's in a text area or a pre-formatted element.

Comment: @lukas.j and @Jordan If you tell someone to use `<br>` as a string in React, then you should also tell them to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @PeterB: you're so right, should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, unless you're trying to display a newline in a `pre` tag, it will be ignored in the browser. You could however store the text content in the state in an array, update that using the `setTimeout` and render this state. You can use `<p>` tags or `<br>` tags to display the text on new lines.

Also, you shouldn't use `map()` as it creates a new array. You could use `forEach()` or a simple for loop instead.

```js
let txt =
  'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur sapiente incidunt molestias beatae voluptas fuga repellendus sit nihil voluptate laudantium delectus aliquam, nulla non suscipit a ea natus voluptatem distinctio!';

function App() {
  let [texto, setTexto] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    txt.split(' ').forEach((line, index) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTexto((prev) => {
          return [...prev, line];
        });
      }, 300 * index)
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {texto.map((word, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{word}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You shouldn't store HTML tags in your state as you will need to use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome :)